Only div tag not closing in TypeScript JSX in VS Code
I have a Next.js App Router app structure setup in VS Code. For some reason, when I type in an opening div tag and close it within a {} in a React component, it does not seem to close the div. I tried other tags and they seem to work but when I do it with div it does not. It seems to work in a TypeScript JSX file (it closes the div tag) but not in this specific code for some reason.
Error which comes up:

Demo:

Code:
"use client";

import type { chats as chatsSchema } from "@/server/db/schema";
import type { InferSelectModel } from "drizzle-orm";
import { type Session } from "next-auth";
import Link from "next/link";
import { Button } from "./ui/button";
import { IconPlus } from "./ui/icons";

export function Sidebar({
  chats,
  session,
}: {
  chats: InferSelectModel<typeof chatsSchema>[];
  session: Session | null;
}) {
  return (
    <div className="relative h-full w-[239px] overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden">
      {!session && (
        <div>
          <span>Log in to save chat history</span>
          <Button variant="link" asChild className="-ml-2">
            <Link href="/login">Login</Link>
          </Button>
        </div>
      )}
      <Button asChild>
        <a href="/">
          <IconPlus className="-translate-x-2 stroke-2" />
          New Chat
        </a>
      </Button>
      {session && <div>} // does not auto close tag here
    </div>
  );
}


VS Code bottom bar:

VS Code Version:
Version: 1.88.1 (user setup)
Commit: e170252f762678dec6ca2cc69aba1570769a5d39
Date: 2024-04-10T17:41:02.734Z
Electron: 28.2.8
ElectronBuildId: 27744544
Chromium: 120.0.6099.291
Node.js: 18.18.2
V8: 12.0.267.19-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631


maybe due to the following </div>. as an experiment, what if you change the outer <div> to something else like <main>?

@user Wait, you're right, that works. That's weird. Why haha. And what can I do about it.

uh. I guess you could be sad that the static analysis isn't smart enough to look at the balancing of various blocks and know what you want :P. you could also raise an issue ticket. the JSX auto-closing stuff is backed by TypeScript itself, so you'd raise the issue ticket in the TypeScript repo. Ex. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45802. If you raise a ticket, please add a link here, or ping me in the ticket with "@starball5". try to create a [mre] (emphasis on "minimal").

@user Submitted here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/58322. Thanks for your help! :)
